# Folder permissions for custom Wordpress uploads folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, file-upload, permissions

I have created a new Wordpress website on my server and done everything as I normally would (nothing fancy or custom, just upload theme, a couple of plugins etc.) except I wanted a custom file path to my media folder.

I have created the folder '/public_html/i', updated my .htaccess file, updated the Setting > Media section in Wordpress with the file path and all is working fine.

My issue is that I do not want the uploads folder to be visible by navigating to the URL (www.site.com/i/). 
If I change the folder permissions to execute only for group / world (711) the images become unavailable / unviewable and although I can still upload they show as broken images.
If I set to execute and read (755) the images and uploads work fine but the folder can be viewed by typing in the URL.

What are the correct permissions I should be using for a custom uploads folder to make images on the site viewable but the containing folder itself not?
Note that this is a site that will regularly have new images uploaded to it, so I would also need to be able to upload without having to change the permissions each time, which is one solution I have found online.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your .htaccess file with the WordPress .htaccess instructions:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you specify which permissions settings I would use? 711?

Comment: You should set it to either 755 or 775.